# Node red write double word

Tags: double, node-red

How do I convert number to double word in Node-red?

I tried throwing the array in
but no response

I'm not very good at node red, please answer me, thank you

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74298035/edit) the question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean converting 'number' to 'double word'?
Data type 'double' is already number type.
Do you mean String to number?

```
[
{
    "id": "bd8884d5c2f82322",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "플로우 1",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "4546977fe7434e95",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "bd8884d5c2f82322",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "1234.34",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 160,
    "y": 40,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a93489fbd55883b2",
            "f1ad7ec076bceb78"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "a93489fbd55883b2",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "bd8884d5c2f82322",
    "name": "Convert String to Number",
    "func": "msg.payload=Number(msg.payload);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 370,
    "y": 40,
    "wires": [
        [
            "1f695a58ebc55f90"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1f695a58ebc55f90",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "bd8884d5c2f82322",
    "name": "number",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 560,
    "y": 40,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "f1ad7ec076bceb78",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "bd8884d5c2f82322",
    "name": "string",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 310,
    "y": 80,
    "wires": []
}]
```